# isAttachedToWindow() returns false

Tags: android, android-view

Can anyone explain why `isAttachedToWindow()` is `false` instead of `true`? I seem to be having attachment issues.

As I understood it, `setContentView(rl)` should attach the `RelativeLayout` to the window.  What am I missing?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            final RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
            setContentView(rl);
            boolean isAttached = rl.isAttachedToWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are performing a view-related action, that change won't actually be executed immediately, rather it would be posted on the [`MessageQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html) of the main thread and later those messages would be handled by the [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)'s next loop event.

Let's speak with a concrete example. Imagine you have a `TextView` with `wrap_content/wrap_content` layout attributes.

```
    TextView textView = ...;
    textView.setText("some fancy text");

    // Will print `0 0`, because this message hasn't yet beet "parsed" by `Looper`
    // Changes will take effect on the next frame
    Log.i("tag", textView.getWidth() + " " + textView.getHeight());

    // Will print `some fancy text`, because this is just a plain Java object
    Log.i("tag", textView.getText());
```

In your case, had you *waited enough* you'd see it eventually being attached. You can be notified about attached state change via [`View#addOnAttachStateChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener)) API.

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is you can't rely on the view to actually be attached to the window in `onCreate()`. You're better off doing your `isAttached()` check after `onStart()`

According to the docs for `onStart()`:

> void `onStart()`
>
> Called after `onCreate(Bundle)` — or after `onRestart()`
>   when the activity had been stopped, but is now again being displayed
>   to the user. It will be followed by `onResume()`.
>
> Derived classes must
>   call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If
>   they do not, an exception will be thrown.

So, once on start is called, the activity is being displayed to the user, which means it's safe to assume your views are attached to the window. Conversely, `onCreate()` may have been called, but the activity might not yet be displaying to the user - so your views might not be attached.

Comment: It will be attached on a traversal of the view hierarchy, such as a layout or draw pass. Which hasn't happened yet in `onCreate()`. It is actually possible to leave an activity without going through `onStart()` - such as if you call `finish()` before getting there - and in that case, the attachment never happens.